# Default Sorting Method

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

When we say Arrays.sort(array) or Collections.sort(List,comparator) , which sorting algorithm is used ? In other words can we assume that the sort() method uses the quickest sorting algorithm ? (For Java)

Comment: In what context are asking, i.e. for what language. Different languages have different implementations

Comment: @AlexiosTsiaparas I believe based on tags he is talking about Java

Comment: @PeterReid Thanks, did not notice !!!

Comment: (I edited :D )thanks guys it is duplicated !